# Spring Controller method being called again with the own method result

Tags: java, spring-mvc, request-mapping

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/area")
public class AreaController {

    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    public String getPage(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        return "asd3333";
    }

}
```

and this is what I get when I access http://localhost:8080/area/1:

- **Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "asd3333"]**

I tested this random return just to show what is happening...
The method is beeing called first with the **@PathVariable = 1** from the request, and then right after that, is called again with the whethever the method resulsts, in this case, it tries to pass the **@PathVariable = "asd3333"**.

I have NO IDEA of what tha heck is happening, pls help

Comment: Perhaps, you meant to use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`

Comment: The first step is always to set your logger at `org.springframework.web: DEBUG` and to post your browser's network tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds very strange indeed. I will start with a question

```
@RequestMapping("/{id}")
public String getPage(@PathVariable("id") int id){
    return "asd3333";
}
```

Does this method need to be called for all method types (Get, Post, Delete, ...). If no try to restrict with a specific method call.

ex

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = POST)
```

GOTCHA.

Also add this to the method because you return a simple string

```
@RequestMapping("/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public String getPage(@PathVariable("id") int id)
```

Also if you don't plan to use this API as a web MVC application but instead as a rest API backend switch from @Controller to @RestController.

Comment: As of a few years ago, `@GetMapping` is usually preferred to `method = GET`.

Comment: Yes, '@ResponseBody' solved it. 
Initially I was trying to render a page with thymeleaf, so that's why I was using '@Controller'.
And I forgot to put the thymeleaf dependencie, and that's why it wasn't working with just a ModelAndView return and no '@ResponseBody'. Thanks